# How to deploy multiple nodes in Corda Testnet network?

Tags: corda

We are building a POC using Corda and Springboot web server.

Following are the versions of Corda platform, Springboot server, and other essential dependencies used for building the POC-

```
cordaReleaseGroup=net.corda
cordaVersion=4.0
gradlePluginsVersion=4.0.45
kotlinVersion=1.2.71
junitVersion=4.12
quasarVersion=0.7.10
spring_version = '4.3.11.RELEASE'
spring_boot_version = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
spring_boot_gradle_plugin_version = '2.1.1.RELEASE'
jvmTarget = "1.8"
log4jVersion =2.11.2
platformVersion=4
slf4jVersion=1.7.25
nettyVersion=4.1.22.Final
```

The CorDapp developed for POC has four nodes -

```
Notary Node
Provider Company Node
Consumer Company 1 Node
Consumer Company 1 Sub Contact Node
```

The POC is running in *dev mode* in our local network.

We require to test the POC in the *Corda Testnet*.

We went through the following documentation on *Corda Testnet* -

1: Join Corda TestNet
URL : https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V4.0/corda-testnet-intro.html?highlight=joining%20corda%20testnet

2: Deploying Corda to Corda Testnet from your local environment 
https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V4.0/deploy-locally.html?highlight=deploying%20corda%20corda%20testnet%20from%20your%20local%20environment

We understood from the above documentation that we can download only one "Corda node" using one registration. Will we have to join the Corda Testnet using four different accounts in order to download four Corda nodes?

Is our understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding you can spin up multiple nodes with a refresh of the Testnet node installation page, or by creating a node and then clicking 'next', which should take you back to the node list and present a button to allow creation of another node.

It should provide you with a unique `ONE_TIME_DOWNLOAD_KEY` each time, and automatically assign you a randomised alphanumeric `O` (organisation) value to use within the nodes configuration file, helping the network map (and thus other nodes on the network) to distinguish your nodes individually.

Make sure you don't unintentionally run copies of the same node with the same identity, otherwise the network map will just assume there has been a change in the address of the original node and route P2P traffic to the newest instance.

Take a look at the `node.conf` docs to understand node configuration further:

https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html

Comment: Thanks.
Following the above suggestion, I could download multiple "node.zips" using the same account.