# Is there a way to programmatically request one-time keys for multiple Corda Testnet nodes?

Tags: corda

I've looked at [this existing Q&A around deploying multiple nodes on the Corda Testnet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57307491/314088). I'm looking at automating deployment of multiple nodes but there seems to be no way documented in the [AWS quickstart for Corda Testnet](https://docs.corda.net/head/aws-vm-explore.html) to grab this line:

```
sudo ONE_TIME_DOWNLOAD_KEY=YOUR_UNIQUE_DOWNLOAD_KEY_HERE bash -c "$(curl -L https://onboarder.prod.ws.r3.com/api/user/node/TESTNET/install.sh)"
```

I can think of one way, involving headless Chromium perhaps to automate the task of grabbing the OTK.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we do not support this currently. One of the reason is that there are a significant amount of active nodes in the testnet. We don't want use to spam the network.